# React infinite scroll crashing on iPhone 6s Plus

Tags: javascript, iphone, reactjs, redux

Has anyone experienced the iPhone 6s Plus crashing with a React.js infinite scroll or similar?

Our slider is a full page image carousel.

Our api is called on the 6th item, and as soon as the 7th loads the browser crashes on an iPhone 6s Plus. Have profiled the memory and there is no obvious memory leak.

Browsers used that fail: Safari and Chrome on iPhone 6s Plus. iOS version 10.2

It has no issues on Firefox/Chrome Samsung Galaxy s5, or iPhone 6s Safari and Chrome.

Any thoughts, speculations, ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: This should be more specific... which browser(s) have you tested it with? What React package are you using? Does it crash on other iPhones as well? What iOS version is running on the iPhone? What do the items look like, what do they contain?

Comment: @Pekka웃 added more info. We are using quite a few packages, I'm starting to wonder if this is a third party package issue here

Comment: How large are the images used? Have you tried with smaller images?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Have tried without rendering images, same issue

Comment: Very strange. Anything in there with huge dimensions? (> 1000 px)

Comment: Yes full page slider @Pekka웃